# Prove $\frac{tf(t)}{\int_0^t f(s)ds}$bounded for a power-like function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $0 = y_0 \leq y_1\leq y_2\cdots y_m =t$, and think of function $f(s)$ defined on $s\in[0,t]$ in the following way (I call this 'truncated iterated integral'?): for fixed integer $m$, let

$g_1(s) = 1$

$g_2(s) = \int_0^{y_1\wedge s} g_1(s)ds$

$\cdots$

$g_m(s) = \int_0^{y_{m-1}\wedge s} g_{m-1}(s)ds$

$f(s) = \int_0^{y_m\wedge s} g_m(s)ds = \int_0^{s} g_m(s)ds$

If the above sequence of iterated integral are of domain $\int_0^s\cdots$ without the $y$'s, then by direct calculation and use a hat notation, we have $\hat{f}(s) = s^m/m!$. This $\hat{f}$ has a property as:

$\frac{s\hat{f}(s)}{\int_0^s \hat{f}(x)dx} = \frac{s\cdot s^m/m!}{s^{m+1}/(m+1)!} = m+1$ for any $s\in[0,t]$

What I want to ask is: with those $y$'s in the integral domain, could we still have similar property, i.e

$\frac{sf(s)}{\int_0^s f(x)dx} \leq m+1$ for any $s\in[0,t]$

My intuition is: this truncated iterated integral $f$ is bounded by a power function for the function values and all orders of derivatives, then this endpoint maximum over the area under the curve should also be bounded by that of the power function.

Does this intuition make sense, if so, any short proof of it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the description above, we want to show

$\frac{sf(s)}{\int_0^s f(x)dx} \leq m+1 = \frac{s\hat{f}(s)}{\int_0^s \hat{f}(x)dx}$

This is equivalent to

$\frac{\hat{f}(s)}{f(s)}\geq \frac{\int_0^s \hat{f}(x)dx}{\int_0^s f(x)dx} = \frac{\hat{f}(C)}{f(C)}$

for some $C\in[0,s]$. The above equality is due to the Cauchy's mean value theorem (guarantee the we could get the same $C$ for numerator and denominator). Hence it would be enough to prove the function $h(s) = \hat{f}(s)/ f(s)$ is non-decreasing. Take derivative and plugin the form of $\hat{f}(s)$, we have this is equivalent to the numerator of $h'(s) \geq 0$, i.e

$h'(s) = \frac{s^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}f(s) - \frac{s^m}{m!}f'(s)\geq 0$

which is further equivalent to

$m\int_0^s g_m(s)ds - sg_m(s)\geq 0$

which is further equivalent to

$\frac{sg_m(s)}{\int_0^s g_m(x)dx} \leq m$

By the above deduction from $f$ to $g_m$, it is ready to use induction to prove the statement. (some trivial details may be involved)